# Logout in Laravel 10 Sanctum

Tags: laravel

I tried the logout operation by deleting all the authenticated tokens as shown in the function below:

```
 public function logout()
{
    auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Logout Successful'
    ], 200);
}
```

The code works fine when i checked the route in Postman, but the error is shown in the controller saying:

```
Undefined method 'tokens'.
```

How do i solve this error?

The screenshot is shown below:
[Controller Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Onl.png)

Comment: Check what return auth()->user(). You can use @var phpDoc annotaition to awoid this warning.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use HasApiTokens in User.php

```
// Revoke all tokens...
$user->tokens()->delete();/
/ Revoke the token that was used to
authenticate the current request...
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();
// Revoke a specific token...
$user->tokens()->where('id', $tokenId)->delete();
```

Comment: the model already includes HasApiTokens

Comment: if you integrate all configuration with Sanctum maybe you need to Run 

composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `auth()->user()` return the Model that has `HasApiTokens` trait. If you are using multiple guards, then ensure `HasApiTokens` trait is included in all the models defined in `guards` and `providers` section of `config/auth.php` file.

If the error is shown in IDE only, then you need to annotate the code to instruct the IDE where to look for the codes.

Eg:

```
/**
 * @var $user App\Models\User
 */
$user = auth()->user();
$user->tokens()->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
confiq/auth.php
add guards

   'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'sanctum',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->group(function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'destroy']);
});


  public function logout(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        /**
         * @var $user App\Models\User
         */

        $user = Auth::guard('sanctum')->user();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated'], 401);
        }

        try {
            // Revoke all tokens for the authenticated user
            $user->tokens()->delete();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Log the exception for investigation
            Log::error('Token revocation failed: ' . $e->getMessage());

            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unable to revoke tokens'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Tokens revoked successfully']);
    }
```